# Linear ODEs are solvable using the common integrating factor

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Well if you happened to check the *Differential Equations, second edition by G.Simmons*, you may see one of his exercises as follows:

- Write equation $$ \frac{dy}{dx} = p(x)y + q(x)$$ in the form of $Mdx +Ndy =0$ (i.e the exact form) *blah blah blah*, show that his equation has an integrating factor $\mu$ that is a **function of x alone**. Find $\mu$ and obtain $$y =e^{-\int p(x)dx}(\int q(x)e^{\int p(x)dx}dx+c) $$ by solving $\mu Mdx + \mu Ndy=0 $ as an exact equation.

Here's my attempt;

To be exact means the satisfaction of the identity
$\frac{\partial}{\partial y}\{\mu (p(x)y-q(x))\} = \frac{\partial}{\partial x}(\mu (1))$

But after you move forward you come across a PDE, which I'm positive it's not asked to be solved by the methods in a PDE course.(however for the curiosity a solution using PDE methods would also be appreciated). The boldface text above is what actually troubles me! Earlier when the author was introducing the method for solving such a problem, he himself got into the same obstacle discussed here, but he then moved forward by **supposing** $\mu$ to be a function of pure $x$. Should I actually do the same thing?

Comment: You just have to find *one* integrating factor. If one that is only a function of $x$ works, you've won already, and don't have to try others.

Comment: I'm perfectly ok with this, but doesn't the question mentioned also dismiss integration factors dependent on either y or y and x together?

Comment: @AshkanRanjbar If you can come up with an integrating factor which depends only on $x$, why would you have any interest in integrating factors that also depend on $y$, for the same equation? Indeed the same situation is routine even in exact equations which aren't linear; dealing with integrating factors that depend on both variables is a real headache.